# Can you pass a class (not an object) as a parameter to a method in python?

Tags: python, static, parameters

I want to do something like the following

```
class A:
  def static_method_A():
    print "hello"

def main(param=A):
  param.static_method_A()
```

I want this to be equivalent to `A.static_method()`.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure. Classes are first-class objects in Python.

Although, in your example, you should use the `@classmethod` (class object as initial argument) or `@staticmethod` (no initial argument) decorator for your method.

Comment: Nope, my answer isn't based on yours. However, I _am_ guilty of writing a one-sentence answer just to get in a first shot, then expanding it within the 5-minute grace.

Comment: This is the same Unknown that was giving me the same garbage the other day... I took my time to write out a thoughtful answer and help someone out and wasn't even paying attention to what anyone else was posting. I gave him a pity +1, but now I regret it. I think everyone needs to stop being so reputation-hungry and just try to help each other out.

Comment: Thanks, Tom, you win; I agree with you totally. (I just replaced my last comment to Unknown with something more sarcastic, just because his picking on other poor users just made me irate.)

Comment: Why do you think I am picking on other users? I am annoyed that people like you and Tom either post nothing or the wrong answer, and then 30 seconds later, I see you and 2 or 3 other people writing the exact same thing as I did.

Comment: @Unknown: You don't get it, do you? To get "first post" often (some) people post a simple one-liner answer and edit it afterwards, exploiting the 5-minute grace to do so. If you didn't answer at all (e.g., if you took a holiday from SO, which I guarantee will reduce your blood pressure :-)), the same answer would have resulted. Trust me on that one.

Comment: To think that you're the only person who could have come up with the answer, and that everyone must be copying you, that's the sense of self-importance I'm talking about. Stop thinking you're Einstein, and your life will go a lot easier, seriously. To be honest, I wish Jeff would implement my favourite feature; once implemented, you can never accuse anyone of copying your answers anymore: http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/general/suggestions/69272-implement-a-twit-filter-

Comment: This is called The Fastest Gun In The West issue. If you are fast enough to get in a simple answer, you will still have a five minute grace period to elaborate on your answer and still maintain your top spot in the order. I've done this numerous times to take a short answer and pile on loads more information and resources. It doesn't mean that anybody is copying anybody else.

Comment: As long as the fast simple answer has useful information in it, I don't mind that it is not completely thorough.  In my opinion, whatever answers the question is sufficient and a speedy response is very useful for the person asking the question.  Going back and changing the answer to be more thorough is useful for future readers who have a similar problem.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do the following (note the `@staticmethod` decorator):

```
class A:
  @staticmethod
  def static_method_A():
    print "hello"
def main(param=A):
  param.static_method_A()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure why not? Don't forget to add @staticmethod to static methods.

```
class A:
  @staticmethod
  def static_method_A():
    print "hello"

def main(param=A):
  param.static_method_A()
```

Comment: Link to python docs (http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod) on static method

Comment: Unknown, don't claim credit for musicfreak's answer or mine. If my post was the only one you commented on that way, I'd let it go; I'm sure enough of my answer to know I copied off nobody. But musicfreak is a newbie to SO; you've got to be better to other users than that. Falsely accusing them of copying you is just...thinking too highly of yourself. :-P

Comment: @Chris its just way too suspicious that you and musicfreak had content-less answers that basically said "yes". Then when I had my staticmethod answer, 1 minute later, both of you changed to have the same answer as I.

Comment: Not suspicious at all - that is the normal way of things on Stack Overflow, when you have a question where a single answer is as obvious as it is here.

Comment: @David if it was obvious then why were there 3 different answers until I came up with mine? And then they all switched?